# Why do I keep getting GetOverlappedResult got err 109

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

So I got a piece of code like this:

```
    mgr = MP.Manager()
    mp_dataset = mgr.dict(dataset)
    mp_seen = mgr.dict({k: None for k in seen})
    mp_barrier = MP.Barrier(WORKER_COUNT + 1)  # +1 to include main process

    # TileQueue is a global var
    workers = [
        MP.Process(target=process_item_worker, args=(TileQueue, mp_dataset, mp_seen, mp_barrier))
        for _ in range(0, WORKER_COUNT)
    ]
    [worker.start() for worker in workers]
    print("Waiting for workers...")
    mp_barrier.wait()

    start_t = time.monotonic()
    try:
        asyncio.run(fetch_more_data())
        elapsed_t = time.monotonic() - start_t
        print(f"\nFetching finished in {elapsed_t:,.2f} seconds", flush=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\nAn Exception happened: {e}")
    finally:
        # Save the results first, convert from managed to normal dicts
        dataset.update(mp_dataset)
        progress["seen"] = dict(mp_seen)
        with PROGRESS_FILE.open("wb") as fout:
            pickle.dump(progress, fout)
        # Then we tell workers to disband
        [TileQueue.put(None) for _ in workers]
        print("Waiting for workers...", flush=True)
        for w in workers:
            w.join()
        TileQueue.close()

    print("Start processing updated dataset")
```

Why a combination of async and multiprocessing? Because the `fetch_more_data` logic is I/O-bound so async works great there, while `process_item` is heavily CPU-bound so I want to dedicate processes to do the heavy stuff.

#### The Issue:

I *always* get the message `GetOverlappedResult got err 109` several times (always equal to `WORKER_COUNT`) prior to the last `print()` line.

Everything works as expected, though. But that message annoys me.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after doing LOTS of experimentation, I found out the (possible) reason:

> I must also 'end' the `Manager()` instance

So I changed the `finally` block to be like this:

```
    finally:
        # Save the results first, convert from managed to normal dicts
        dataset.update(mp_dataset)
        progress["seen"] = dict(mp_seen)
        with PROGRESS_FILE.open("wb") as fout:
            pickle.dump(progress, fout)
        mgr.shutdown()
        mgr.join()
        # Then we tell workers to disband
        [TileQueue.put(None) for _ in workers]
        time.sleep(1.0)
        TileQueue.close()
        print("Waiting for workers...", flush=True)
        for w in workers:
            w.join()
```

Now I no longer get the `GetOverlappedResult got err 109` and I'm happy :-)